# Google Protocol Buffers: c.toArray is not a function when setting a date value on my request

Tags: request, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build a create request for `grpc-web`. I've got my protocol buffers generated and I can successfully fetch information but I'm having trouble creating a request.

Eg.

```
const request = new PricingMethodRequest()
request.setCurrencyId(64)
request.setId(0)
request.setFrequency(1)
request.setFromDate({ nanos: 0, seconds: 1555064508 }) // <--- Crashes on this line
...
```

It seems like I keep getting `TypeError: c.toArray is not a function` when I try to set a date value. Or even a price value which is also an object.

How do I implement setting a date value, or any value that's expecting a JavaScript object?

**Edit:**

I've seen stuff online that I could do something like this:

```
const fromDateAny = new proto.google.protobuf.Any.fromJavaScript({ nanos: 0, seconds: 1555064508 })
request.setFromDate(fromDateAny)
```

But doing this gives me the error `Cannot find name 'proto'`.

Comment: What's the .proto definition of that message? By the way, this is not a grpc nor grpc-web question. This is more a protobuf question. Please consider re-tagging. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've been so confused as to what it what regarding gRPC and protocol buffers. I've updated the question. But I found an answer which I'll post shortly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out I had to create a `Timestamp` type for the `fromDate`.

I did that by doing this:

```
import * as timestamp_pb from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/timestamp_pb'

...

const timestampFromDate = new timestamp_pb.Timestamp()
timestampFromDate.setSeconds(fromdate.seconds)
timestampFromDate.setNanos(fromDate.nanos)

request.setFromDate(timestampFromDate)
```

**Edit:**

I've found a cleaner way to read and write these functions is just by chaining them. E.g. the final request being build would look like this:

```
const request = new PricingMethodRequest()
  .setCurrencyId(64)
  .setId(0)
  .setFrequency(1)
  .setFromDate(
    new timestamp_pb.Timestamp()
      .setSeconds(1555064508)
  )
```

Comment: Did you just figure this out by trial and error or did you find some docs that explained this as the way to do it?

Comment: Mostly trial and error, I think in the end I looked deeper into my protobuf definitions to explore how they work.