# google-protobuf error from REACT: TypeError: c.toArray is not a function

Tags: grpc, grpc-web, protocol-buffers

Any idea about this error?

TypeError: c.toArray is not a function
Function.push../node_modules/google-protobuf/google-protobuf.js.jspb.Message.setWrapperField

grpc server implemented in python.
grpc-web client is in REACT.

proto message:

```
message DatasetPath {
google.protobuf.StringValue FolderPath = 1;
}
```

Error comes when calling this javascript code:

```
const datasetPath = new DatasetPath();
datasetPath.setFolderpath("/"); //Error TypeError: c.toArray is not a function
```

protoc compilation =>

```
protoc datasets.proto -I=../protobufs --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=commonjs,mode=grpcwebtext:.
```

versions used:
"google-protobuf": "^3.15.5",
"grpc-web": "^1.2.1",

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

`import * as google_protobuf_wrappers_pb from 'google-protobuf/google/protobuf/wrappers_pb'`

`const folderPath = new google_protobuf_wrappers_pb.StringValue(["/"])`

`datasetPath.setFolderpath(folderPath as google_protobuf_wrappers_pb.StringValue)`

See: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/3823

And see here: [Google Protocol Buffers: c.toArray is not a function when setting a date value on my request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55630469/google-protocol-buffers-c-toarray-is-not-a-function-when-setting-a-date-value-o)